# Montart loop com variáveis para exclusão com PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Após um filtro tenho esse form com os usuários e seus serviços, o que estou tentando fazer é enviar as informações para deleção dos registros com os parâmetros setados no form, no caso seria o ID do Usuário e o Serviço, na sequência vou inserir os que estiverem com check marcados, ou seja, podem ser vários registros ao mesmo tempo sendo enviados.

Esse é o meu formulário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As minhas variáveis estão assim no meu form:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="Check[]"  class="checkbox1" <?php if ($retorno >= 1) { echo "checked='checked'"; } ?> value="<?php echo $IdUsuario;  ?>">
 <input name="IdUsuario" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $IdUsuario;  ?>" />  
 <input name="IdServico" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $IdServico;  ?>" />              
 <input name="IdInterface" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $IdInterface;  ?>" /
```

Estou precisando executar um `loop` para uma efetuar uma exclusão do meu `BD`, mas não tenho como fazer esse loop, pois só recebo as variáveis vinda de um form, existe alguma maneira de fazê-lo somente com essas variáveis?

As variáveis que recebo são essas:

```
$IdUsuario = (isset($_POST['IdUsuario'])) ? $_POST['IdUsuario'] : '';
$IdServico = (isset($_POST['IdServico'])) ? $_POST['IdServico'] : '';
```

O meu código de exclusão está assim:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `gasUsuarioServico` WHERE `IdUsuario` = :IdUsuario AND `IdServico` = :IdServico";
$stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
$stm->bindValue(':IdUsuario', $IdUsuario, ':IdServico', $IdServico);
$retorno = $stm->execute();
```

Comment: Não estou entendendo, pode oferecer mais detalhes? Por que você não pode usar essas variáveis no loop?

Comment: Olá @MagicHat, justamente é esse a minha dificuldade, como montar um loop com variáveis.

Comment: Deixa eu tentar entender a situação... Pelo que percebo os dados contidos nas variáveis são únicos(pois são ids), o loop executa uma ação repetidas vezes até que uma condição seja satisfeita, entretanto nesse caso(aparentemente) você não poderá executar a ação mais do que uma vez... Então aí que não estou entendendo a  necessidade do loop... Tente explicar mais detalhadamente o funcionamento desse processo que deseja, ex: de onde vão vir os valores desses ids(embora vc tenha mencionado de um form)... Quero dizer, será enviado 1 usuário e serviço por vez?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom eu fiz o código baseado no seu.

Deixei documentado no código.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['check'])){ //Verifica se tem algum usuário selecionado

   $checked = $_POST['check'];//Posicoes selecionadas

   $IdUsuario = $_POST['IdUsuario']; //Array de usuarios
   $IdServico = $_POST['IdServico']; //Array de Servicos
   $IdInterface = $_POST['IdInterface']; //Array de Interfaces

   $total = count($checked); //Quantidade de usuários selecionados

    for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++){ //Varrer eles

        //echo $IdUsuario[$checked[$i]]; //Usuario selecionado
        //echo $IdServico[$checked[$i]]; //Servico selecionado
        //echo $IdInterface[$checked[$i]]; //Interface selecionado

        $sql = "DELETE FROM `gasUsuarioServico` WHERE `IdUsuario` = :IdUsuario AND `IdServico` = :IdServico";
        $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
        $stm->bindValue(':IdUsuario', $IdUsuario[$checked[$i]], ':IdServico', $IdServico[$checked[$i]]);
        $retorno = $stm->execute();        
    }    
}
?>
<form name="form1" method="post"> <!-- Formulário -->
<?php 
    //Dados colocados fixos, mas deve alterar para a sua busca
    $db_usuarios = array( 
                    array("user"=>"Usuário 1",
                          "usuario"=>"1",
                          "servico"=>"1",
                          "interface"=>"1"),
                    array("user"=>"Usuário 2",
                          "usuario"=>"2",
                          "servico"=>"2",
                          "interface"=>"2"),
                   array("user"=>"Usuário 3",
                          "usuario"=>"3",
                          "servico"=>"3",
                          "interface"=>"3")
                );

   $total_usuarios = count($db_usuarios); //Alterar para a sua busca

for($i=0; $i<$total_usuarios; $i++){ //Criar os usuários dinamicamente
?>

<input type="checkbox" name="check[]"  class="checkbox1" value="<?php echo($i); ?>"><?php echo($db_usuarios[$i]['user']); ?>
<input name="IdUsuario[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo($db_usuarios[$i]['usuario']); ?>" /> 
<input name="IdServico[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo($db_usuarios[$i]['servico']); ?>" />   
<input name="IdInterface[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo($db_usuarios[$i]['interface']); ?>"/>

<?php

}

?>

<input type="submit" value="Enviar"> <!-- Enviar -->

</form>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela grande ajuda @Everson, muito interessante essa solução.